# Application crashes when selecting image

Tags: android, android-intent, action

I want to ask that I am selecting an image from gallery in my app. I used intent to open the gallery in my app. Here is the code:

```
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

When I tried to select big image size of more than 1MB. It unfortunately stopped, otherwise its working fine. Can somebody tell me why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, whenever you post a question related to a crash, its best to post the crash logs so that other people can help you exactly!

But luckily for you, this is a very common form of crash. It happens mostly due to `OutOfMemoryException` in Android, when you play around with big images. The crash happens because in Android you are working with limited memory, and you are trying to load a big image in your app.  Ideally you should to load a lower resolution version of the image in memory.

There is a specific section in the developer website, [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), try going through that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

While you load large bitmap files, BitmapFactory class provides several decoding methods (decodeByteArray(), decodeFile(), decodeResource(), etc.).

**STEP 1**

Setting the inJustDecodeBounds property to true while decoding avoids memory allocation, returning null for the bitmap object but setting outWidth, outHeight and outMimeType. This technique allows you to read the dimensions and type of the image data prior to construction (and memory allocation) of the bitmap.
To avoid java.lang.OutOfMemory exceptions, check the dimensions of a bitmap before decoding it.
To tell the decoder to subsample the image, loading a smaller version into memory, set inSampleSize to true in your BitmapFactory.Options object.

For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384. Loading this into memory uses 0.75MB rather than 12MB for the full image.

Here is my code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                Uri imageUri;
                try {
                     imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Image Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                //final InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                //final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                ShrinkBitmapConverter sh = new ShrinkBitmapConverter(getActivity());
                Bitmap selectedImage = null;
                try {
                    selectedImage = sh.shrinkBitmap(imageUri,450,350);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Image Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                statusImage = ImageConverter.imageToStringConverter(selectedImage);
                if(statusImage.length()>512000){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Image is too big",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    postImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                }
        }
    }
```

ImageConverter.java:

```
public class ImageConverter {

    public static String imageToStringConverter(Bitmap image){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        String imageToString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return imageToString;
    }

    public static Bitmap stringToimageConverter(String imageString){
        byte[] stringTobyte = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stringTobyte, 0, stringTobyte.length);
        return bmp;
    }

}
```

ShrinkBitmapConverter.java:

```
public class ShrinkBitmapConverter {
    Context context;
    public ShrinkBitmapConverter(Context c){
        context=c;
    }

    public Bitmap shrinkBitmap(Uri uri,int width,int height) throws FileNotFoundException {

        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = null;;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri),null,bmpFactoryOptions);

            int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
            int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

            if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
            {
                if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
                {
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
                } else {
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
                }
            }

            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri),null,bmpFactoryOptions);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Image Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Please read this link for details. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, optionsImage);<<<this line

Comment: `code` optionsImage.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(optionsImage, 160, 160);     
`code`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, optionsImage); <<this line

Comment: I don't think you need to use decodeFile.You may have to use decodeStream if you are using it from gallery.I have edited my code.Don't just copy the code.try to understand and use the part of code that u required.Chill..

Comment: I just copied the method which returned sample size .. because i am encoding image in base64 , I didn't copied whole code

Comment: I have edited my code.It won't give Null pointer exception.I have handled it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your manifests under application.

Add this

android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:largeHeap="true"